# How to check if my CPU is banned from interrutps in the /proc/interrupts file?

Tags: linux, operating-system, linux-kernel, scheduling, interrupt

I am running irqbalance with the option IRQBALANCE_BANNED_CPUS=3e, which means ban everything but cpu0 (111110). Now I want to make sure it is working but when I check the file /proc/interrupts I see a bunch of interrupts everywhere. Why are interrupts 21, 22, 24 and 35 going to other cpus if they are banned? I did rebooted my machine after changing /etc/default/irqbalance to include the IRQBALANCE_BANNED_CPUS=3e option. Did I configure anything incorrectly? Is it irqbalance not working correctly? Is it doing what it is suppose to do and I cannot get rid of those interrupts? I can see irqbalance is running with ps -ef.

```
           CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3       CPU4       CPU5       
   0:         30          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      timer
   1:          2          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      i8042
   6:          3          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      floppy
   8:          1          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      rtc0
   9:          0          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   acpi
  12:          4          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      i8042
  14:      44724          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      ata_piix
  15:          0          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      ata_piix
  18:          0          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   ata_piix
  19:          2          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   ohci1394
  20:          3          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   ehci_hcd:usb2, uhci_hcd:usb3, uhci_hcd:usb6
  21:        197        635         40          0         84          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   uhci_hcd:usb4, uhci_hcd:usb7, HDA Intel
  22:        344       3506          0      25325          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   ehci_hcd:usb1, uhci_hcd:usb5, uhci_hcd:usb8
  24:        162       1094          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   nvidia
  35:        174          0       1101          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   nvidia
  53:      14925          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      eth0
 NMI:          0          0          0          0          0          0   Non-maskable interrupts
 LOC:      51553      42038      28305      28788      15486      13981   Local timer interrupts
 SPU:          0          0          0          0          0          0   Spurious interrupts
 PMI:          0          0          0          0          0          0   Performance monitoring interrupts
 PND:          0          0          0          0          0          0   Performance pending work
 RES:       1068       1679        330        136        129        140   Rescheduling interrupts
 CAL:       5151       3746       2015       5438       5439       5437   Function call interrupts
 TLB:       6508       7306       4202       3051       1777       1046   TLB shootdowns
 TRM:          0          0          0          0          0          0   Thermal event interrupts
 THR:          0          0          0          0          0          0   Threshold APIC interrupts
 MCE:          0          0          0          0          0          0   Machine check exceptions
 MCP:          6          6          6          6          6          6   Machine check polls
 ERR:          5
 MIS:          0
```

EDIT1: Well, I now changed to IRQBALANCE_BANNED_CPUS=1 and I get the same thing. It looks my configuration is just not working. :( But why?

```
            CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3       CPU4       CPU5       
   0:         26          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      timer
   1:          2          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      i8042
   6:          3          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      floppy
   8:          1          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      rtc0
   9:          0          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   acpi
  12:          4          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      i8042
  14:       6912          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      ata_piix
  15:          0          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      ata_piix
  18:          0          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   ata_piix
  19:          2          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   ohci1394
  20:          3          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   ehci_hcd:usb2, uhci_hcd:usb3, uhci_hcd:usb6
  21:        197        290        282          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   uhci_hcd:usb4, uhci_hcd:usb7, HDA Intel
  22:        188        372          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   ehci_hcd:usb1, uhci_hcd:usb5, uhci_hcd:usb8
  24:         67          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   nvidia
  35:         74          0          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   nvidia
  53:       2369          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      eth0
 NMI:          0          0          0          0          0          0   Non-maskable interrupts
 LOC:       3626       2764       2321       2364       2043       1168   Local timer interrupts
 SPU:          0          0          0          0          0          0   Spurious interrupts
 PMI:          0          0          0          0          0          0   Performance monitoring interrupts
 PND:          0          0          0          0          0          0   Performance pending work
 RES:        185        188        192        124         77        133   Rescheduling interrupts
 CAL:        214        272        280        273        141        281   Function call interrupts
 TLB:        186        455        251        152        138         73   TLB shootdowns
 TRM:          0          0          0          0          0          0   Thermal event interrupts
 THR:          0          0          0          0          0          0   Threshold APIC interrupts
 MCE:          0          0          0          0          0          0   Machine check exceptions
 MCP:          2          2          2          2          2          2   Machine check polls
 ERR:          5
 MIS:          0
```

Comment: Good question, but this is off-topic for SO. Probably belongs on either [su] or [sf].